# How to remove right most None from pandas.tolist()?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

Suppose I import `xlsx` file to list:

[image]

```
pd.read_excel(open('1.xlsx','rb'), index_col=None, header=None).values.tolist()

[[nan, 1.0, 2.0, nan],
 [nan, 3.0, nan, nan],
 [nan, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
 [nan, 7.0, nan, nan]]
```

Is it possible to remove right most `None` without looping through the lines? Expected result:

```
[[nan, 1.0, 2.0],
 [nan, 3.0],
 [nan, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
 [nan, 7.0]]
```

Comment: nothing immediately obvious or clean. since the output has uneven length rows, just iterate and truncate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### NumPy based solution

```
# reverse the columns 
a_rev = a[:,::-1]
# indices of all values after first nan to True
m = np.cumsum(~np.isnan(a_rev), 1) >= 1
# indices where to split
s = np.cumsum(m.sum(1))
# reverse again
ix = m[:,::-1]
# split to obtain n arrays
res = np.split(a[ix], s)[:-1]

print(res)

[array([nan,  1.,  2.]),
 array([nan,  3.]),
 array([nan,  4.,  5.,  6.]),
 array([nan,  7.])]
```

To get a nested list:

```
list(map(list, res))
[[nan, 1.0, 2.0], [nan, 3.0], [nan, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [nan, 7.0]]
```

---

Setup:

```
import numpy as np

nan = np.nan
a = np.array([[nan,  1.,  2., nan],
              [nan,  3., nan, nan],
              [nan,  4.,  5.,  6.],
              [nan,  7., nan, nan]])
```

---

#### Using lists

```
l = [[nan,  1.,  2., nan], [nan,  3., nan, nan], 
     [nan,  4.,  5.,  6.],  [nan,  7., nan, nan]]

out = []
for i in l:
    i_rev = i[::-1]
    for ix, j in enumerate(i_rev):
        if j == j:
            out.append(i[:len(i)-ix])
            break

out
# [[nan, 1.0, 2.0], [nan, 3.0], [nan, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [nan, 7.0]]
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought there is a `read_excel` option for doing that. And I get an error `ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types...` in a row `m = np.cumsum(~np.isnan(a_rev), 1) >= 1`

Comment: Try with `pd.read_excel(open('1.xlsx','rb'), index_col=None, header=None, dtype=float).values.tolist()` @F.Vosnim
`

Comment: Timing the approaches the second seems to be 4 times faster @F.Vosnim So I'd suggest using lists here